# Storing scrapy queue in a database

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to store the url queue in a database so that it can be shared by multiple instances of scrapy running on different machines.

I've found that there is a queue API that I need to implement and then register my queue using SPIDER_QUEUE_CLASS setting. However, I cannot find anywhere how the API that should be implemented looks like. Is it still available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scrapy internal queue uses [queuelib](https://github.com/scrapy/queuelib)

> Queuelib goals are speed and simplicity. It was originally part of the Scrapy framework and stripped out on its own library.

its "api" is rather simple, see the way `push` and `pop` [are used by scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/squeue.py), your implementation might look like:

```
DatabaseFifoQueue = _serializable_queue(myqueue.DatabaseQueue, \
_pickle_serialize, pickle.loads)
...
```

Comment: Also take a look at scrapy-redis as an example https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-redis